# cannot change text of div on the website

Tags: html

so basically I have few divs on the website which can be edited by a user, so basically when user clicks on div they should be allowed to change text inside that div. If I right click on the website I can then change the text of a div but if I left click on the div, nothing happens. This only happens to a div with id `editTxt` while for a different div it works ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
        <link href="http://localhost/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"/>
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="true" id ="editTxt" class="draggable ">
<p>Main title for the website</p>
    </div>
<div  contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable "><p>Change Text inside this box</p></div>


</div>
</body>
</html>

$(function() {
    $('.content-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content-link2').load($(this).attr("href"), function() {
            $('#content, #content2, #content3, #editTxt').draggable({
                containment: "#content-link2",
                scroll: false
            });
            $( "#content, #content2, #content3, #editTxt" ).resizable({
                containment: "#content-link2",
                scroll: false,
                handles: 'all',
                maxHeight: 300,
                maxWidth: 300,
                minWidth: 100,
                minHeight: 100,
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: working example please.

Comment: Is working fine here. What browser are you using?